# why can I only get 250 rows (/shoe transactions) of stockx data when accessing their API?

Tags: json, api, web-scraping

I have tried to gather data directly from the API of stockx which seemed possible according to an article from Jan 2019: https://medium.com/@thewillmundy/stockx-sneaker-data-in-three-simple-steps-8977d0016b80 . I am thereby able to get a request url which gives me some transactions in JSON-format.

I have tried changing the parameters within the request url (limit as well as page), which is possible, but only for the latest 250 transactions (due to high volume of sales for some shoes, I can thereby only receive the sales history for the last few days)...

My Goal: getting the whole sales history (often several thousand transactions) - in the article mentioned above, thats possible

- Could it be a restriction from stockx?
  or is there a way?

Would be so so grateful for help!!!
Best regards, Marvin

Answer (score 0):

I think the API will only give you the 250 most recent sales because that's all the product webpage itself will allow you to load when you click view all sales. Any sales further back in time aren't directly accessible from the product page, and we're essentially requesting the same data that page can request using the link it would use. I guess those are stored and accessed in a different way internally.

I'm guessing StockX changed its API since that article is a little old. I would try to contact StockX about their API via email, but I don't think they're really continuing developer support:
https://twitter.com/stockx/status/1000004306844647424?lang=en

It's pretty disappointing because I was also looking to work with the sales data but what can you do :/